# Running docker stack deploy not able to connect to app. Docker-compose works fine

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to get a very simple docker-swarm going. If I start the container using `docker-compose up -d` I am able to go to locahost and see the 'Hello message'.
Running `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml swar` starts the swarm fine.
docker ps

[image: dockerps]

docker service ls

[image: docker service ls]

However navigating to localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 or IP of machine doesn't work, it just timesout with 'This site can't be reached. took too long to respond.'
Ive also tried it with another small tutorial from github, which also has same issue.
Any ideas what is wrong?

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const os = require("os");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from Swarm " + os.hostname());
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: takacsmark/swarm-example:1.0
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.1.0-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD npm start
```

EDIT:
running wget < my computer ip > just hangs.

```
--2021-05-28 16:59:52--  http://<ip>/
Connecting to <ip>:80...
```

curl < ip > just hangs no output.

Ive initialised the swarm included advertise ip aswell

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <my address>
```

And still no luck.

My docker version is 20.10.5, docker-compose version: 1.25.0

Comment: It might be worth noting that `docker stack deploy` does not honor the build: directive, so unless the image has been built locally recently, it will try and deploy an image with that name from docker hub. you can just go `docker-compose build` which will build each service with a build: attribute and automatically tag it with any image: attribute. which will work for a single node. Otherwise you will need a registry to host custom images that all nodes can reach.

Comment: I should have menttioned that, I did build image with compose, was part of tutorial step aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone ever getting this sort of problem. Problem was the version of docker. Ive removed 20.10.15 and reinstalled a docker 19.03.10. To install custom docker instead of latest follow steps. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
locahost doesnt work, but run `hostname -I` to get the ip of your machine and paste that in. Will work then.